# Angular translate service, interpolate params in nested json

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-translate, ngx-translate

In angular translation service, interpolating params in normal translation json works well. But in nested json, interpolating params is not working.

My JSON:

```
  "SampleField": {
    "SampleValidation": {
      "MIN": "Value should not be less than {{min}}", 
      "MAX": "Value should not be more than {{max}}", 
    }
  }
```

My Angular Code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.translateService.get('SampleField.Validation', {
    // using hard coded value just as a sample
    min: 0, max: 2000
  }).subscribe(translation => {
    console.log(translation);
  });
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    MIN: "Value should not be less than 0",
    MAX: "Value should not be greater than 2000"
}
```

Actual Output:

```
{
    MIN: "Value should not be less than {{min}}",
    MAX: "Value should not be greater than {{max}}"
}
```

Comment: Just a typo issue ? `SampleField.Validation` => `SampleField. SampleValidation `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [source of ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) interpolation works only on strings:

```
export abstract class TranslateParser {
/**
 * Interpolates a string to replace parameters
 * "This is a {{ key }}" ==> "This is a value", with params = { key: "value" }
 * @param expr
 * @param params
 * @returns {string}
 */
abstract interpolate(expr: string | Function, params?: any): string;
```

This means you might need to use an array of keys instead of a non-leaf element:

```
this.translateService.get([
    'SampleField.Validation.MIN', 
    'SampleField.Validation.MAX'
  ], {
  // using hard coded value just as a sample
  min: 0, max: 2000
}).subscribe(translation => {
  console.log(translation);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using the `translate` pipe, so that you can remove the additional service dependency to your component.

```
<p *ngIf="!item?.isRemovable">
{{'i18n.dashboard.heading' 
| translate:{'TEXTTOFIND': 'STRINGTOREPLACE'} }}
</p>
```

Just make sure that your key `i18n.test.key` has this `TEXTTOFIND` interpolated. Something like below.

```
"heading": "This is with the interpolated {{TEXTTOFIND}} text."
```

Note the `{{}}` in the heading string and the `STRINGTOREPLACE` can be anything you wish.